# Samsung Galaxy s3 can't edit contacts much

Tags: contacts, photos

When I click on the 'edit' icon for a contact, the only options I get are to change their name, phone number and email address. The default profile picture disappears so I can't change their picture. Can't add additional information. Can't favourite them. I know you can go to favourites, or image gallery (and pick an image), and then pick a contact to allocate (as a favourite or the image), but my contact list turns up empty when I try this route. Even though I have contacts. Has anyone else had this problem or know how to fix it?

Comment: Are you using the stock `Contacts` app, or a 3rd-party app?

Comment: Excuse my ignorance, if by stock contacts app you mean the one that comes with the phone (orange phone book icon with white person outline), then that one :) thankyou

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out - the contacts were saved to my SIM card, not my phone. I had to import all my contacts from my SIM to my phone and then I was able to edit them fully :)